# How are functions implemented?

Tags: function, pointers, go

I've been playing around with the `reflect` package, and I notice how limited the functionality of functions are.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(strings.ToUpper)
    fmt.Printf("Address: %v\n", v)               // 0xd54a0
    fmt.Printf("Can set? %d\n", v.CanSet())      // False
    fmt.Printf("Can address? %d\n", v.CanAddr()) // False
    fmt.Printf("Element? %d\n", v.Elem())        // Panics
}
```

Playground link [here](https://play.golang.org/p/qAOxS1nsm0).

I've been taught that functions are addresses to memory with a set of instructions (hence `v` prints out `0xd54a0`), but it looks like I can't get an address to this memory address, set it, or dereference it.

So, how are Go functions implemented under the hood? Eventually, I'd ideally want to manipulate the `strings.ToUpper` function by making the function point to my own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Disclaimers:

1. I've only recently started to delve deeper into the golang compiler, more specifically: the go assembler and mapping thereof. Because I'm by no means an expert, I'm not going to attempt explaining all the details here (as my knowledge is most likely still lacking). I will provide a couple of links at the bottom that might be worth checking out for more details.
2. What you're trying to do makes very, very little sense to me. If, at runtime, you're trying to modify a function, you're probably doing something wrong earlier on. And that's just in case you want to mess with any function. The fact that you're trying to do something with a function from the `strings` package makes this all the more worrying. The `reflect` package allows you to write very generic functions (eg a service with request handlers, but you want to pass arbitrary arguments to those handlers requires you to have a single handler, process the raw request, then call the corresponding handler. You cannot possibly know what that handler looks like, so you use reflection to work out the arguments required...).

---

Now, how are functions implemented?

The go compiler is a tricky codebase to wrap ones head around, but thankfully the language design, and the implementation thereof has been discussed openly. From what I gather, golang functions are essentially compiled in pretty much the same way as a function in, for example, C. However, calling a function is a bit different. Go functions are first-class objects, that's why you can pass them as arguments, declare a function type, and why the `reflect` package has to allow you to use reflection on a function argument.

Essentially, functions are not addressed directly. Functions are passed and invoked through a function *"pointer"*. Functions are effectively a type like similar to a `map` or a `slice`. They hold a pointer to the actual code, and the call data. In simple terms, think of a function as a type (in pseudo-code):

```
type SomeFunc struct {
    actualFunc *func(...) // pointer to actual function body
    data struct {
        args []interface{} // arguments
        rVal []interface{} // returns
        // any other info
    }
}
```

This means that the `reflect` package can be used to, for example, count the number of arguments and return values the function expects. It also tells you what the return value(s) will be. The overall function "type" will be able to tell you where the function resides, and what arguments it expects and returns, but that's about it. IMO, that's all you really need though.

Because of this implementation, you can create fields or variables with a function type like this:

```
var callback func(string) string
```

This would create an underlying value that, based on the pseudo code above, looks something like this:

```
callback := struct{
    actualFunc: nil, // no actual code to point to, function is nil
    data: struct{
       args: []interface{}{string}, // where string is a value representing the actual string type
        rVal: []interface{}{string},
    },
}
```

Then, by assigning any function that matches the `args` and `rVal` constraints, you can determine what executable code the `callback` variable points to:

```
callback = strings.ToUpper
callback = func(a string) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("a = %s", a)
}
callback = myOwnToUpper
```

I hope this cleared 1 or 2 things up a bit, but if not, here's a bunch of links that might shed some more light on the matter.

- Go functions [implementation and design](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bMwCey-gmqZVTpRax-ESeVuZGmjwbocYs1iHplK-cjo/pub)
- Introduction to [go's ASM](https://golang.org/doc/asm)
- Rob Pike on the go compiler written in go, and the plan 9 derived [asm mapping](https://talks.golang.org/2016/asm.slide#1)
- Writing a [JIT in go asm](http://nelhagedebugsshit.tumblr.com/post/84342207533/things-i-learned-writing-a-jit-in-go)
- a "case study" attempting to [use golang ASM for optimisation](https://blog.sgmansfield.com/2017/04/a-foray-into-go-assembly-programming/)
- Go and assembly [introduction](http://www.doxsey.net/blog/go-and-assembly)
- Plan 9 assembly [docs](https://9p.io/sys/doc/asm.html)

---

### Update

Seeing as you're attempting to swap out a function you're using for testing purposes, I would suggest you *not* use reflection, but instead inject mock functions, which is a more common practice WRT testing to begin with. Not to mention it being so much easier:

```
type someT struct {
    toUpper func(string) string
}

func New(toUpper func(string) string) *someT {
    if toUpper == nil {
        toUpper = strings.ToUpper
    }
    return &someT{
        toUpper: toUpper,
    }
}

func (s *someT) FuncToTest(t string) string {
    return s.toUpper(t)
}
```

This is a basic example of how you could inject a specific function. From within your `foo_test.go` file, you'd just call `New`, passing a different function.

In more complex scenario's, using interfaces is the easiest way to go. Simply implement the interface in the test file, and pass the alternative implementation to the `New` function:

```
type StringProcessor interface {
    ToUpper(string) string
    Join([]string, string) string
    // all of the functions you need
}

func New(sp StringProcessor) return *someT {
    return &someT{
        processor: sp,
    }
}
```

From that point on, simply create a mock implementation of that interface, and you can test everything without having to muck about with reflection. This makes your tests easier to maintain and, because reflection is complex, it makes it far less likely for your tests to be faulty.

If your test is faulty, it could cause your actual tests to pass, even though the code you're trying to test isn't working. I'm always suspicious if the test code is more complex than the code you're covering to begin with...

Comment: For the record, I'm only modifying functions at runtime for my test code. Sometimes it's hard to gain coverage on functions which return errors.

Comment: @hlin117: In that case, I sincerely believe we're dealing with an X-Y problem here. There are plenty of ways to inject mock functions to use during testing. I'll update my answer adding a simplistic example

Answer (score 1):

Underneath the covers, a Go function is probably just as you describe it- an address to a set of instructions in memory, and parameters / return values are filled in according to your system's linkage conventions as the function executes.

However, Go's function *abstraction* is much more limited, on purpose (it's a language design decision). You can't just replace functions, or even override methods from other imported packages, like you might do in a normal object-oriented language. You certainly can't do dynamic replacement of functions under normal circumstances (I suppose you could write into arbitrary memory locations using the [unsafe](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) package, but that's willful circumvention of the language rules, and all bets are off at that point).

Are you trying to do some sort of dependency injection for unit testing?  If so, the idiomatic way to do this in Go is to define interface that you pass around to your functions/methods, and replace with a test version in your tests. In your case, an interface may wrap the call to `strings.ToUpper` in the normal implementation, but a test implementation might call something else.

For example:

```
type Upper interface {
   ToUpper(string) string
}

type defaultUpper struct {}

func (d *defaultUpper) ToUpper(s string) string {
    return strings.ToUpper(s)
}

...

// normal implementation: pass in &defaultUpper{}
// test implementation: pass in a test version that
//      does something else
func SomethingUseful(s string, d Upper) string {
    return d.ToUpper(s)
}
```

Finally, you can also pass function values around. For example:

```
var fn func(string) string
fn = strings.ToUpper

...

fn("hello")
```

... but this won't let you replace the system's `strings.ToUpper` implementation, of course.

Either way, you can only sort of approximate what you want to do in Go via interfaces or function values. It's not like Python, where everything is dynamic and replaceable.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to replace functions for unit testing purposes. I know the idiomatic solution is to use interfaces to mock behaviors, but injecting interfaces make the code more cluttered...

Comment: Unfortunately, what you're trying to do is fighting against the design of the language, and the cure may be deadlier that the sickness :( . Also, many (including myself) might argue that defining explicit interfaces adds clarity to your code and more clearly conveys your design intentions. It's a language design choice, and Go is pretty opinionated towards doing things its own way. Some people hate it, but there's certainly value to be had by having a code base with consistent style and structure (enforced at the language level in this case).